# How to match a specific string using -match in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, match

I have a text (.txt) file, example shown below:

```
1 SHA1 <KEY1>
2 SHA1 <KEY2>
10 SHA1 <KEY3>
11 SHA1 <KEY4>
20 SHA1 <KEY5>
21 SHA1 <KEY6>
```

To get the required output, I use:

```
$content = Get-Content -Path C:\Files\test.txt
$content -match "10 SHA1"
10 SHA1 <KEY3>
```

All fine so far.

```
$content -match "20 SHA1"
20 SHA1 <KEY5>
```

Still the expected output, all good.

```
$content -match "1 SHA1"
1 SHA1 <KEY1>
11 SHA1 <KEY4>
21 SHA1 <KEY6>
```

Not good. Desired output:

```
1 SHA1 <KEY1>
```

How can I get an exact match using `-match` ?

Comment: The right operand for `-match` is treated as a regular expression, so the results aren't always what you expect if you are looking for a simple equality check, etc.  In your case, `-like` might be a better option: `$content -like "1 SHA1*"`, `$content -like "10 SHA1*"`.  Even `$content -like "10*"` would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It matches all 3. If you use a start of line anchor, then it will work.

```
@"
1 SHA1 <KEY1>
2 SHA1 <KEY2>
10 SHA1 <KEY3>
11 SHA1 <KEY4>
20 SHA1 <KEY5>
21 SHA1 <KEY6>
"@ -split '\r?\n' -match "^1 SHA1"

1 SHA1 <KEY1>
```